# Using ClosedXML cells get trimmed

Tags: c#, closedxml

I have the following sample code. The problem that I am having is that the for column one at the section where I am showing the Comments, it get trimmed. What I like to do is to show the comments have it span as many fields as it needs to. Currently it gets trimmed. I am using Excel 2010.

```
 var path = Path.Combine(driveLetter, "Sample", "Report_-Blank.xlsx");

 XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook(path);

 //Read worksheet at position 1 i.e. First worksheet in excel
 var ws = workbook.Worksheet(1);

 // Facility Tested
 ws.Cell(1, 19).Value = "TestLocation";
 ws.Cell(1, 19).Style.Font.FontSize = 20;

 // Date of Collection
 ws.Cell(2, 19).Value = "10/12/2013";
 ws.Cell(2, 19).Style.Font.FontSize = 20;

 // Collector's Email
 ws.Cell(3, 19).Value = "james@gmail.com";
 ws.Cell(3, 19).Style.Font.FontSize = 20;

 // LabId
 ws.Cell(5, 19).Value = "1344";
 ws.Cell(5, 19).Style.Font.FontSize = 20;

 // Date Analyzed
 ws.Cell(6, 19).Value = "12/3/2013";
 ws.Cell(6, 19).Style.Font.FontSize = 20;


 // Sample #
 ws.Cell(20, 1).Value = "1";
 ws.Cell(20, 1).Style.Font.FontSize = 20;
 ws.Cell(20, 1).Style.Border.OutsideBorder = XLBorderStyleValues.Thin;

 // Location 
 ws.Cell(20, 2).Value = "Closed Loop1";
 ws.Cell(20, 2).Style.Font.FontSize = 20;
 ws.Cell(20, 2).Style.Border.OutsideBorder = XLBorderStyleValues.Thin;

 // Comments

 ws.Cell(22, 1).Value = "COMMENTS:";
 ws.Cell(22, 1).Style.Font.FontSize = 25;
 ws.Cell(22, 1).Style.Font.Bold = true;
 ws.Cell(22, 1).Style.Font.Underline = XLFontUnderlineValues.Single;

 // Comment 1
 ws.Cell(23, 1).Value = "Sample 1: Test is a test of how to display sample 1 445454@ ";
 ws.Cell(23, 1).Style.Font.FontSize = 20;
 ws.Cell(23, 1).Style.Border.OutsideBorder = XLBorderStyleValues.Thin;

 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 workbook.SaveAs(ms);

 return ms;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the cells to the right are empty Excel should display the text from the comment cell over the empty cells. If that is not the case, you can merge some cells to get more space:

```
ws.Range(23, 1, 23, x).Merge().Value = "Sample 1: ...";
```

where `x` is the number of cells you want to merge.

If there are not enough empty cells to make space for the comment, you could also active wrapping:

```
ws.Cell(23, 1).Style.Alignment.SetWrapText(true);
```